# Python Regex: "re.match()" works differently than "re.sub()" for regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to check if my string contains some regular expression.

The strange thing is is, that while `re.sub()` would find the regex and will replace it, `re.match()` does not return any results...

Here is my usage:

**re.match()**: - trying to match the pattern `,\s*param2` - nothing is returned

```
>>> str = 'func(param1, param2)'
>>> str
'func(param1, param2)'
>>> results = re.match(r',\s*param2', str)
>>> print(results)
None
```

**re.sub()**: - Successfully replacing the same pattern `,\s*param2` by " hello"

```
>>> str = 'func(param1, param2)'
>>> str
'func(param1, param2)'
>>> new_str = re.sub(r',\s*param2', ' hello', str)
>>> new_str
'func(param1 hello)'
```

How can I match the pattern `,\s*param2` without substituting it?

Comment: `re.match` matches from the beginning of the string. Have you tried `re.search`?

Comment: Is `re.search` the same as `re.match` except for the "beginning" thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) matches from the beginning of the string. You are probably looking for [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search). See [search vs. match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match) for some details.

```
>>> str = 'func(param1, param2)'
>>> re.match(r',\s*param2', str)
>>> re.search(r',\s*param2', str)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f16b72b83d8>
```